# SQL Server Reporting Services filter with operator "like"

Tags: reporting-services, filter, sql-like

I added the filter which uses the parameter with operator like (to show all rows that include entered text in the column). I did it like this:

```
=" * " + Parameters!Roles.Value + " * " .
```

But if I enter nothing(or leave it `NULL`) in parameter, it won`t show rows where this column is EMPTY. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your Filter Expression to resolve to a Boolean result (True or False).  Then change your Filter Data Type to Boolean, your Operator to = and your Value to True.  Now you can add to your expression to cater to null values - use the IsNothing function.

Comment: But then I won`t be able to enter text for filter to show all rows with entered text..

Comment: Why not?  You can code as complex an expression as you need - look at the Like operator and Switch function.